# ¿Donde y como le asigno una variable a un dato proveniente de una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

He desarrollado una página web donde manejó varios usuarios. Uno de estos usuarios ingresa a la pagina y tiene que iniciar sesión por lo cual tiene asignado un `login`.

Lo que quiero es que al iniciar sesión, esté usuario, en la página pueda ver información suya tal como el `nombre`, el `id` y un `comentario`.

Todos estos datos están guardados en la base de datos pero no logro traer esta información sin mostrar la de los demás.

Cuento con tres archivos:

- Uno es el `login` donde el usuario valida datos.
- El segundo es la conexión a la base de datos donde le digo que variables debe evaluar y donde creo yo debo asignar las variables que necesito.
- Y el tercer archivo donde muestro tal información de la sesión iniciada.

Aquí el código de la conexión, en el `if` se puede ver la variable de sesion con la que logro mostrar únicamente el `id` de dicho usuario.

```html
<?php
try{
 
 $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=guarderiajp" , "root", "");
 
 $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM datos_alumnos WHERE USUARIOS= :login AND PASSWORD= :password";
 
 $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

 
 $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
 
 $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
 
 $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
 
 $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);
 
 $resultado->execute();
 
 $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();
 
 if($numero_registro!=0){
  
  //echo "<h2>Adelante!!</h2>";
  
  session_start();
  
  $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];

  
  header("Location:acudiente.php");
```

Luego de esto en la pagina donde supone muestro los datos he escrito el siguiente código:

```html
<?php

echo "hola " . $_SESSION["usuario"];

?>
```

Mi duda es como consigo ver más información de dicho usuario como he mencionado ya varias veces anteriormente.

Comment: Hay una par cosas que deberías considerar cambiar: 1.- ¿Por qué usas `htmlentities(addslashes($var))`? Ya empleas sentencias preparadas. 2.- Deberías [encriptar las contraseñas](https://jonsuh.com/blog/securely-hash-passwords-with-php/#targetText=PHP%205.5%2B%20now%20comes%20baked,storing%20user%20passwords%2C%20no%20excuses.) 3.- Deberias hacer `die();` inmediatamente despues del `header("Location:acudiente.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Te dejare un ejemplo como yo lo hice:

```
$genero="SELECT * from Genero";
$querygen =mysqli_query( $condb,$genero);
$gen=mysqli_fetch_array($querygen);
$generoemp=$gen['Descripcion'];
```

En tu caso seria meter el id del usuario seleccionado y colocar un query con una condicion que traiga x datos del id que pasas como parametro